# Programmatically set a view's color to ?android:attr color attributes

Tags: android, android-dark-theme, android-color

I need to programmatically set a view's color to ?android:attr/textColorPrimary which is an attribute from the android's dark theme compatible attributes. Now it is possible to get colorButtonNormal with

```
R.attr.colorButtonNormal
```

But not ?android:attr/textColorPrimary and ?android:attr/colorBackground. Is there anyway to also get these attributes programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `android.R.attr.textColorPrimary`.

Something like:

```
    val typedValue = TypedValue();
    theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.textColorPrimary, typedValue, true);
    val color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, typedValue.resourceId)
```

In Java:

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.colorSecondary, typedValue, true);
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, typedValue.resourceId);
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Tho I'm coding with java and it looks a little different.

Comment: @Prs2 I've updated the answer with the same code in java